# sugarcrm: adding extra fields to a relationship

Tags: php, relationship, sugarcrm

I am playing around with SugarCRM CE 6.5.16.

I've created 2 modules with the module builder: Club and module (to make it a bit confusing, the module is actually called module :))
These 2 are related to each other so that I can show that a certain club uses a certain module. one club can have multiple modules, and one module can be used by many clubs, so this is a many-to-many relationship.

Next to this, I also want to register since when they're using it and when they used it for the last time. For this, I already added the fields used_since and last_usage to the database table club_module_c. The data for the field is coming from an external system and is already loaded into the database.

What I now would like is to make this data visible in the "module" subpanel of the club. There's no need to edit it there, it only needs to be readable. Doesn't seem like there's a standard way to do this in SugarCRM.

I've only found one solution for it: http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f148/howto-add-additional-data-many-many-relationship-only-viewing-50719/ But I don't seem to get it working, maybe things changed in the meanwhile since that thread is almost 5 years old.

There's also another solution around: http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/10/04/adding-fields-to-a-relationshipsubpanel/ A bit less old, but way more complicated, mentioning all kind of files that my SugarCRM doesn't have...

Any ideas?

Comment: Jason Egger's guide to doing this is the best way of doing it. It's complicated and difficult, but he spells it about as well as it can be. For an example in your system, look in the Opportunity/Contact relationship. That's what his post is based off of.

Comment: @ErikL if you ended up solving this, consider posting your findings on an answer to your own question. Maybe you could just say which files you ended up changing and we can mimic that while following Jason Egger's tutorial at the same time. I would appreciate (and use) such information.Thanks.

Comment: I have been able to get the sample from Jason Egger working, but getting it to work with 2 different (custom) modules is another cup of thee, I've tried it, with a bit of guess work with what file should go where (this differs between the standard modules and custom modules), but whatever I tried, all I got working where step 1 & 2. Everything beyond that didn't seem to trigger any change in the system.

I must say I'm a bit disappointed in sugarCrm, having to jump through such a lot of hoops for a functionality that should just be a basic part of any crm system kind of makes me sad..

Answer (score 0):

Researched this for a while and there's another solution supplied here: https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/developer-help/8797-how-create-custom-field-on-accounts-contracts-relatiship-module but it's a little bit light on details and there's no way for an end user to modify the value of the field, but maybe that's what you're looking for.

Otherwise I would suggest the following which is based on Jason's tutorial but with certain changes:
https://youtu.be/rSkVKhuEPnE